# How to change small chainring

Tags: gears, crankset, chainring, mechanical

I have a bike with a 46/36T crankset (FSA Gossamer Cross BB30) and I'd like to change the small chainring to an even smaller one.

​Googling around ​suggests that the smallest chainring I can get for a 110mm BCD crankset is 33T. Is that right?

Furthermore, it seems that I won't need to replace anything else at all, not even the chain. I run an [Ultegra RD-6800-SS](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/ultegra-6800/RD-6800-SS.html) rear mech with an 11-28T cassette and all the specs seem to check out:

- Max front difference: 16T (in my case, 46-33=13).
- Total capacity: 33T (in my case, (46-33)+(28-11)=30).

So just swap out the chainring and good to go, or am I overlooking something? (Never done this before.)

Finally, how do I make sure that the chainring I buy is compatible with my drivetrain? It seems that the BCD (110mm) is all that matters, so something like [TA 110 PCD Zephyr](http://www.wiggle.com/ta-110-pcd-zephyr-inner-road-chainring/) would work?

P. S. As I am looking at a picture of the Zephyr chainring, I notice that it says "9/10 speed". What does that mean exactly? (My drivetrain is 11-speed.)

P. P. S. [This page](https://r2-bike.com/Specialites-TA-Kettenblatt-Lochkreis-110-ZEPHYR-Innen_1) lists what looks like the same product as compatible with 8/9/10/11 speeds, but with the following cryptic remark: *"For 10-/11-speed drives only with 1 or 2-speed crank handle!"* Are they simply trying to say it's too thick for a triple chainset or does this refer to something else?

[image: TA 110 PCD Zephyr]

Comment: Simply *reaching* the chainring may be a task.  Probably easiest would be to remove the crank arm.  But a 9-10 ring may be too wide for an 11 chain.  (I lost track of the details about the time that 7s came out.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Thanks. That's what I am wondering too. [This page](https://r2-bike.com/Specialites-TA-Kettenblatt-Lochkreis-110-ZEPHYR-Innen_1) lists what looks like the same product as compatible with 8/9/10/11 speeds, but with the following cryptic remark "Note: For 10-/ 11-speed drives only with 1 or 2-speed crank handle!" Are they just trying to say it's too thick for a triple chainset?

Comment: Depending on the length of your chain you might need to remove two links.  If the derailleur is taking up as much as it can at 36/11 you might go slack at 33/11.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Oh yeah, I haven't thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: Random bit of trivia: In some systems (at least Campagnolo at the time 10-speed come out) the chainrings are the same but the thickness of crank spider varies. So it's the crank that also determines spacing between rings. I think road triples went out of fashion before 10-11 speed became common.

Comment: A 110mm BCD chainring fits over an installed crank. Best done with the bike on a stand! Remove the rear wheel then the 5 bolts on the rings, guide the large ring over the crank, then the small one. You might have to remove a large pedal. Reassemble in the opposite way. I do this regularly when swapping between 52/36 and 50/34. It works perfectly well.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Extreme cross-chaining like 33-11 might cause another problem like the chain rubbing on the large ring. I'd better avoid that combination, maybe even 33-13.

Comment: @Carel:  there are various views on cross chaining.  I do it frequently.  Whatever the smallest cog you use with the small chainring, changing to a smaller small chainring might make there be too much chain.

Comment: just checking how this went? I’m also looking to change the small chainringfrom an FSA 46/36 to hopefully 46/30 - I struggled to find a small enough chainring so was just going to replace the whole crank as the GRX 46/30 looks to do the job. Is there any compatibility issues that I’d need to check for the front derailleur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most drivetrain setups have a 16 tooth difference between large and small rings.

- Near compact: 52/36
- Compact: 50/34
- Sub compact: 48/32

You are trying to get a close to a super compact on a 110mm BCD and will have a chainring tooth difference of 13.

That means the rear derailleur will easily accommodate this as you have calculated.

The *front* derailleur will also handle the chaining size difference.

Chain length is set on the large chainring and largest cog sprocket, so you should not have to shorten the chain (assuming your chain is correctly sized to begin with). You will be within the derailleur total capacity so it will take up the extra slack.

If you do have too much slack in small ring and smallest sprocket, check the chain is sized properly.

Comment: If they added 50 links they would be within the capacity but the derailleur wouldn’t take up the slack. Chain should be assessed once the new ring is installed

Comment: What does 'if they added 50 links' mean?

Comment: It’s hyperbole to picture how the chain could be too long for the smallest gear

Comment: Well, yeah. If the chain is the wrong length there will be an issue. I made a small edit '(assuming your chain is correctly sized)...'. I guess the chain could be too long, but as chains are sized on the biggest ring and sprocket it seems unlikely.

Comment: Actual suggestion: you could word it like “you should _only_ shorten the chain if there is too much slack for the derailleur in 33x11”

Comment: I don't really want to argue this point ad infinitum, but ... the proper procedure for sizing a chain is on the large chainring and largest sprocket, otherwise you run the risk of the chain being too short. If the chain is then too slack in the small ring and smallest sprocket, the derailleur does not have enough capacity - which we think will not be the case here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81415/discussion-between-argenti-apparatus-and-swifty).